# How get data from array in json item using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a little Issue.. My items have attributes and each attribute is used like 
key and value.

I need put value from attribute key desctiption in my page.. but i dont know how do it.

Here is my json data

```
[
{
    "id": 2323,
    "name": "small ring",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "key": "weight",
            "value": "90"
        },
        {
            "key": "description",
            "value": "A little ring"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2324,
    "name": "big ring",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "key": "weight",
            "value": "90"
        },
        {
            "key": "description",
            "value": "A Big ring"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here is my html body.

```
<div class="list-group ">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items " class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <span  style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="pull-left">
        {{item.name}}
        <p><small>{{item.attribute}} </small></p><!-- Here -->
    </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
<div class="list-group ">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items " class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <span  style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="pull-left">
        {{item.name}}
        <p><small>
            <span ng-repeat="attr in item.attributes" ng-if="attr.key == 'description'">{{ attr.value }}</span>
        </small></p>
    </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This should work. It loops through the attributes but should only display the attribute if its key is equal to `description`.

Comment: hmmm is a nice solution.. thnkx for help :D

Comment: @BrunoNovais - No problem! Make sure to mark my answer as correct if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Yah.. only waiting for Stackoverflow allow me choice correct answer